# How to combine the contents of multiple files in powershell

Tags: powershell, file-io, powershell-3.0

I was wondering how I would go about combining specific files together using powershell. Example: I want to take `EDIDISC.UPD` `EDIACCA.UPD` `EDIBRUM.UPD` ETC ETC ETC ETC and Combine the contents of these files together and make a new file named `A075MMDDYY.UPD`. Now I would want it to be able to be run by whomever has the `.UPD` files on their network drive. Such as example: Mine would be in `N:\USERS\Kevin`, someone else's may be in `N:\USERS\JohnDoe`.

So far I only have:

```
Param (
  $path = (Get-Location).Path,
  $filetype = "*.UPD",
  $files = (Get-ChildItem -Filter $filetype),
  $Newfile = $path + "\Newfile.UPD"
)
$files | foreach { Get-Content $_ | Out-File -Append $Newfile -Encoding ascii }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing just on the aspect of concatenating (`cat`ting) the contents of multiple files to form a new file, assuming the current directory (`.`):

```
$dir = '.'
$newfile ="$dir/Newfile.UPD"
Get-Content "$dir/*.UPD" -Exclude (Split-Path -Leaf $newFile) | 
  Out-File -Append -Encoding Ascii $newFile
```

- You can pass a wildcard expression directly to `Get-Content`'s (implied) `-Path` parameter in order to retrieve the contents of *all* matching files.
- Since the output file is placed in the same dir. and matches the wildcard expression too, however, it must be *excluded* from matching, by *filename*, hence the `-Exclude (Split-Path -Leaf $newFile)` argument (this additionally assumes that there's no input file whose name is the same as the output file's).